# dynamic parameter size and line object crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am using visual studio 2013 and crystal report. I will preview the report in crystal report preview. and pass in the value in the .cs file which consist of the preview of CR.

I want to do something like image below

[image]

I use box object & line object to draw the table and use text object as the text, for data I will use parameter to show.

How can I do dynamic box size(using line and box object) depend on the parameter length??

if the incident detail has only 500 words, then the height of incident detail will fit to the words. if it has 1000 words, the heigh should be extend.

your comment and suggestion is much appreciated!

Comment: Place the incident details in text box...  and length extend to size of report and for height check can grow option and set value to zero

Comment: @Siva how can I put the parameter to textbox? I try drag it into the textbox its not working? mind explain furture? Thanks you very much

Comment: you should be able to drag.. if that is not possible then you can create a formula field and place your data in formula and follow the same process as followed for text field